# PHP and HTML Echo

Tags: php, html

I want to query a result from a table. The problem I run into is if the text is very long it will not auto-wrap to another line"best way i can think to explain it". It displays the text on one line and will go way off to the side of the page if the text is long. How can I get the text to space correctly. Thanks

here is my code:

```
<?php
    echo "<div class=\"item_list2\">";
    $get_items = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE category='Art'";
    $result = mysql_query($get_items);
    //loop! loops through the multiple results of the $get_items query
    while($item = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        echo "<b>" . $item['item'] . "</b><br/>" . $item['email'] . "<br/>";
        echo $item['price'] . "</b><br/>" . $item['category'] . "</b><br/>" . $item['extra'];
        echo "<br/><a href='manage.php?delete=" . $item['id'] . "'><small>[Delete]</small></a><br/><br/>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
 ?>
```

Comment: Looks like it's entirely HTML problem. Try to get your long text and experiment with some HTML/CSS. When finished - just add these tags to your PHP output

Comment: Can you provide a link, anyway, this is not the way to do this, there is a better solution.

Comment: Does the text not have spaces in it?  It should wrap if it does.  Whats the item_list css style look like?

Comment: Need more info on what your text looks like in the db or on an example page.

Comment: You're HTML is pretty messy; there's some serious abuse of the `<br />` element going on here, and you have an un*opened* `<b>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use CSS to break it.

```
.container
{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: `\n` doesn't affect how HTML renders. It's interpreted the same as a space.

Comment: @Matchu, you're right! Read the user wrong. Though he was talking about sorce code.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to add..

```
nl2br($item['extra']);
```

Comment: white-space:pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;

:)